# Is the gas constant really a constant?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, ideal-gas

For ideal gases we have 
$$
C_p-C_v=R
$$
now the left hand side of this equation is temperature dependent, so how is it possible that gas constant $R$ is temperature independent?

Comment: Food for thought: can any combination of two functions equal a constant? For instance, $f(x) + g(x) = C$? It's pretty easy to imagine lots of times that is true -- $f(x) = -g(x) \rightarrow C = 0$ or $f(x) = x; g(x) = -x+10 \rightarrow C = 10$ etc.. No reason to think that couldn't happen with specific heats also.

Answer (score 1):

The Molar Specific Heat at constant volume $C_v$ is:
$$\frac{fR}{2}$$
and the Molar Specific Heat at constant pressure $C_p$ is:$$\frac{(f+2)R}{2}$$

($f$ is the degrees of freedom of a molecule of the gas in concern, and $R$ has its usual meaning.)

If you verify, the difference (i.e. $C_p-C_v$) is always $R$ regardless of the value of $f$.